# Dummy Coding Multiple-Select Race/Ethnicity

Tags: regression, categorical-data, categorical-encoding

I'm performing some survey research and am looking to include race/ethnicity as an independent variable in a regression model. Normally, race/ethnicity would be added to the model as a set of dummy codes. However, we ask race/ethnicity as multiple-select multiple choice questions, so the responses are not necessarily mutually exclusive.

My first thought was to create and include a dummy code for each option (so n, as opposed to n-1). While those dummy codes would not be mutually exclusive, can I consider each an "independent dummy code" of sorts? For example, consider the "American Indian/Alaska Native" dummy code separate from the "Asian" dummy code. A 1 in "Asian" would be saying that the participant identifies as Asian with the reference group as those that do not. Is this a reasonable Solution?

If not, do you have any suggestions on how to handle this type of data?

If this is a reasonable solution, might this process have any impacts in the conclusions I can draw regarding race/ethnicity in this model?

Comment: While there may be multiple choice answers for some of the questions, it should be possible to enumerate all the possible distinct combinations and then map those (except one for baseline) to dummy variables. Can you give a sample example of the single vs. multi answers?